# Splitting lists within a 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.6

Say I have a 2D list called `sentences`.

```
sentences = [['hello'],['my'],['name']].
```

Is there anyway to split these lists up every character into separate indexes, so it would look like:

```
sentences = [['h','e','l','l','o'],['m','y'],['n','a','m','e']
```

For example:
 sentences.txt =

```
hello
my
name
```

The code I've written:

```
sentence = open('sentences.txt', 'r')
sentence_list = []
new_sentence_list = []
for line in sentence:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    sentence_list.append(line)
for line in sentence_list:
    line = [line]
    new_sentence_list.append(line)
```

This would result in `new_sentence_list` to be:

```
[['hello'],['my'], ['name']].
```

When I would like it to be:

```
[['h','e','l','l','o'],['m','y'],['n','a','m','e']
```

Comment: If you do `list('hello')` you will end up with `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `list(line)` to achieve this:

So, your code becomes below, where your original line is commented.

```
sentence = open('sentences.txt', 'r')
sentence_list = []
new_sentence_list = []
for line in sentence:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    sentence_list.append(line)
for line in sentence_list:
    line = list(line)
    # line = [line]
    new_sentence_list.append(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Very straightforward with a list comprehension:

```
new_sentences = [list(sentence[0]) for sentence in sentences]
```

Applied to

```
sentences = [['hello'],['my'],['name']]
```

yields

```
[['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['m', 'y'], ['n', 'a', 'm', 'e']]
```